# Can Eclipse ADT still be used for Android Development?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

Can Eclipse in conjunction with ADT still be used for Android Development (and if yes, how do I go about it) or should I just keep using Android Studio?
I tried setting up ADT on my Eclipse, but it wouldn't work (after many, many tries).
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Android Studio is the only thing that Google support

Answer (score -1):

yes you can but the best practice for android development is by using Android Studio because linux users has also problem with eclipse. you can take help from below link

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

but as per my suggestion you should use Android Studio because if you are using eclipse then you need to migrate the code also.

Comment: "because linux users has also problem with eclipse" - citation needed. Your entire first paragraph is outright wrong. Android Studio is the [only _officially supported_ IDE](https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/11/02/google-officially-ends-support-for-eclipse-android-developer-tools-in-favor-of-android-studio/). Eclipse also works perfectly fine on Linux, and that would either way not have anything to do with why Android Studio is recommended.